# Kafka transactional producer throws 'Timeout expired while initializing transactional state in 60000ms'

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-transactions, spring-kafka-test

I have configured a Kafka ProducerFactory with a transactionIdPrefix, in order to enable transaction synchronization using `@Transactional` (see [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#transaction-synchronization) on producer-only transactions).

I'm running an EmbeddedKafka in my integration test, to see how it behaves.

The logs show the following :

```
DEBUG 8384 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  :
    [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=tx-0-0]
    Sending transactional request (type=FindCoordinatorRequest, coordinatorKey=tx-0-0, coordinatorType=TRANSACTION) to node 127.0.0.1:61445 (id: -1 rack: null)

DEBUG 8384 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   :
    [Producer clientId=producer-1, transactionalId=tx-0-0]
    Enqueuing transactional request (type=FindCoordinatorRequest, coordinatorKey=tx-0-0, coordinatorType=TRANSACTION)

Timeout expired while initializing transactional state in 60000ms.
```

This is thrown when DefaultKafkaProducerFactory executes `newProducer.initTransactions()`.

My configuration is the following :

**IntegrationTest**

```
@EmbeddedKafka(brokerProperties = { "transaction.state.log.replication.min.isr=1", "transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1" })
```

**ProducerConfig**

```
@Bean
  public ProducerFactory<String, String> transactionalProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configuration = new HashMap<>();

    configuration.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, properties.getBootstrapServers());
    configuration.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configuration.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    String transactionIdPrefix = "tx-0-";
    configuration.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, true);
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String> factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configuration);
    factory.setTransactionIdPrefix(transactionIdPrefix);

    return factory;
  }

@Bean
  public KafkaTemplate<String, String> transactionalKafka() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(transactionalProducerFactory());
  }
```

Spring-Kafka version : 2.2.7.RELEASE

I don't see how to move forward, I think that I followed every step from the documentation and the communication between the Kafka client and the broker should be fine during transaction initialization.
Could anyone please help me fix this?

Comment: It looks ok (similar to one of the framework tests https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/523fa05a7898130811d658dd63411b392be8da12/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplateTransactionTests.java#L90-L93) I suggest you enable debug logging for the server - I can take a look if you can post a complete minimal project that exhibits this behavior).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @garyrussell.
I am using logback in the project, I read that as spring-kafka-test is using log4j I should add a log4j.properties file, but I don't find any documentation on how to control the embedded kafka server logs, so I don't have them so far.

Comment: spring-kafka-test is not "using log4j" where did you read that? It looks like the kafka broker uses slf4j-api so it should work with logback as long as you have the slf4j binding for it.

Comment: That's right, we had the following line in logback.xml :
<logger name="kafka" level="OFF"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve the problem thanks to the embedded kafka server logs.

Property `transaction.state.log.min.isr` defaulted to 2, I had to overwrite it with `transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1` to fix the server error. After that my integration test passed.

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue but adding this property to the properties file does not resolve it for me. Did you have to do anything else to fix the issue?

Comment: Can you post your Kafka server logs here ?

Comment: Turns out the property added was not being picked up until I deleted my kafka docker container and recreated it. This works now. Thanks.